# How to add a loader in my react app after I signin or register a user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader

I'm having some issues to add a loader whenever I'm fetching data from my API.
Basically whenever I click on signin or register, It doesn't show a loader and it confuses the user as while the app fetches the data there's nothing happening in the frontend, therefore the user doesn't know if the app is running.

Here's my repo: https://github.com/JUANCA99COL/face-recognition-app

[image: here's my loader script]

[image: here's the app.js script]

Any help or suggestion would be great!

I've tried using `useffect()`, but seems like the API I'm using is not fetching.

Answer (score 1):

set initial setIsLoading as "true" so initially it will be show the loader then when API is called in the useEffect it will change the state setIsLoading to "false" to disable the loader.

also use E(false) to change the state as in your state
"const [setIsLoading, E] = useState(true)"

setIsLoading will be used to get the value of the state and E() is the function to update that state

below is the corrected code,

const [setIsLoading, E] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {

```
fetch('https://login-app-api-ap19.onrender.com/image', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: this.state.user.id
        })
      })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    setData(data);
    E(false);
  });
```

}, []);